# Css - shadow overlays other elements

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have few div and each of them has a shadow, but the shadow of a div always overlays the next div.

here is my code:
html:

```
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px black;
}
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/81t4v4a5/

I want to accomplish something like that but without a container : https://jsfiddle.net/kc98heaw/

Is that possible?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Why are you averse to using a container when containers are a big part of the box model? Why are each line of text in their own div if you only want the style on a single parent div? Is the second fiddle you linked the version you want?

Comment: the second link is what I want to achieve without using a contaienr since there are some other behaviors I want to apply that cant be done if all of the divs are wrapped in a container

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y6097xso/

I tried to iterate through all divs and draw the shadow with an expression:

```css
div {
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px black;
}
div:nth-child(2n){
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 9px 0 4px -4px black, -9px 0 4px -4px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
```

Comment: Almost, it doesnt look quite right with the shadows of the second child, can you expain what you did there?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i messed up a little in the shadows, is this one better?

Comment: You should update your answer with the fixed JSFiddle and code, not just put that in the comments. Users in the future should see the actual answer contained within the answer block.

Comment: sorry, its my first time using stack overflow and answering a question :p

Comment: It still isnt quite right, im looking for it to be perfect, and can you explain what you did there? I want to understand it